# SELECT DISTINCT FROM <subquery> GROUP BY HAVING Query in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I want to write a query in SQLAlchemy, which is the equivalent of the following,

```
SELECT DISTINCT <column>
FROM <subquery> AS result
GROUP BY <columns>
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

I already have the subquery that I want to use, but I am not sure how to add the rest of it. How can I implement this?

Comment: It seems like your query has some contradictions or redundancies. Can you give some data examples? That would probably help with determining exact what you need.

Comment: What contradictions do you mean?

Comment: Maybe contradictions aren't the right word, but it is very confusing what you are trying to do. Usually you don't use distinct then group by then having counts = 1. I would be happy to help if I had some sample data or perhaps a better idea of waht you were trying to accomplish